# How to read a file in "to" endpoint or inside a processor using camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to read a file inside a `to` endpoint or inside a processor.

Is there an easy way to do this? (I can always use normal `File IO code` inside processor to read the file but I am trying to find if there is a camel way of doing this).

i.e.

```
from("direct:mycustomEndpoint")
.to("readfilehere");
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: See the Content Enricher EIP: http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

Answer (score 0):

Below will help to read file as file in Apache Camel Processor

```
       from("file://target/input?delay=1000")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange msg) {
                File file = msg.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                .............
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like this:

```
<pollEnrich>
   <constant>file:/test/?fileName=file_index.txt&amp;noop=true</constant>
</pollEnrich>
```